Scattering into an edge state
In the optical context, a photon can excite an electron from the valence band to the conduction band if the photon energy is higher than the gap. I would like to know is it possible to photoexcite an electron from valence band to an itinerant edge state inside the gap?

Can you please provide a bit more context?  For example, are there particular materials you have in mind?  This might be helpful.  Thank you.

Interband transition is a well-known optical phenomenon in solid state physics. For example you can find a brief explanation in the following link; https://www.fkf.mpg.de/4678244/interband-transitions.pdf
